# Add reference in code with C#?

Tags: c#

I am looking for the equivalent of C++'s #pragma comment(lib, "name"); but for C# and adding assembly references. How can i do it?

Comment: Do you want to reference a native library or another .NET assembly?

Answer (score 3):

Please see:

[Calling a C++ lib from C#](http://geeklit.blogspot.com/2006/08/calling-c-lib-from-c.html)

[Call Unmanaged DLLs from C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/cc301501.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you can dynamically add a reference via code.

However you could load the needed assembly via Reflection in code (Assembly.LoadXXX methods) and then access the types defined in it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) through [DLLImport] as in the example below:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern Boolean MessageBeep(UInt32 beepType);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, because the C# compiler *needs* the reference beforehand to be able to generate the IL, whereas the C++ compiler has header files that describe the layout of the referenced libraries (at least from a parser/verification perspective - it needs the LIB in the generation phase to actually be able to write the offsets)